# Something as easy as drupal_write_record for reading

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-6

Does drupal have a simple version for reading like `drupal_write_record`. I want to read a record from a table called `{allcategories}` and find the record that has a `category` field of value `computers`. It's a custom table defined with schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for doesn't really exist in Drupal 6. [drupal_write_record just barely made it into Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/169982). In Drupal 7, the database API itself makes this straightforward enough that I wouldn't expect another abstraction layer like "drupal_read_record":

```
$record = db_select('allcategories') // table
    ->condition('category', 'computers') // field & value
    ->execute() // do it
    ->fetch(); // get the result
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = db_query('SELECT a.* FROM {allcategories} a WHERE a.category="%s"', 'computers');
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  print $row->[YOURCOLUMNNAME].'<br/>';
  // other actions...
}
```

Comment: +1 but I know about `db_query`. I was hoping there was `drupal_read_record` or something like that.

Comment: ah, forgot to say about this, wait for drupal 7 :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, drupal does not have ORM support. A contirbuted ORM module does exists in development state
http://drupal.org/project/orm/

Comment: The ORM module clearly indicates it's for nodes only, and the question clearly indicates it's not dealing with nodes, so this answer isn't very useful.